# extracting text from html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get nodes containing text from html file using Javascript and jQuery.
if I have a node like 
`

```
<div>txt0
<span>txt1</span>
txt2
</div>
```

`How can I select elements that meets this criteria??
Meaning, I need to retrieve the`div`and the`span` , and it would be even better to know location of the text.

I'm trying to get the text to replace it with images in a later function.
I tried this

`

```
$('*').each(function(indx, elm){
   var txt = $(elm).text();
   // my code to replace text with images here
});
```

`

but it does not get the required results.. it does all the parsing in the first element, and changes the html totally.

Comment: Are you wanting to select all the elements that have text in them?

Comment: What does `<div>txt0<span>txt1</span>txt2</div>` get changed to after you manipulate it?

Comment: @lix Yes,
@ JuanMendes: I'll change them when I find them

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to solve, but perhaps you can be a bit more specific with your selector?

```
$("div span").text(); // returns 'txt1'
$("div").text();      // returns 'txt0txt1txt2'
```

By adding ids and/or classes to your html, you can be very specific:

```
<div class="name">Aidan <span class="middlename">Geoffrey</span> Fraser</div>
```

...

```
// returns all spans with class
// "middlename" inside divs with class "name"
$("div.name span.middlename").text(); 

// returns the first span with class
// "middlename" inside the fourth div 
// with class "name"
$("div.name[3] span.middlename[0]").text();
```

JQuery has pretty [good documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) of these selectors.

If this doesn't help, consider explaining the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup structure is a bit uneasy. Consider changing to something like this

```
   <div>
     <span>txt0</span>
     <span>txt1</span>
     <span>txt2</span>
   </div>
```

Then using jQuery

```
$("div span").each(function(k,v) {
   $(this).html("<img src=\""+v+".jpg\" />"); //replace with the image
});
```